# How can i display image in image link?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i want to create a image link but can't see the image
it's my Extension methods:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString ActionImage(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
 string controller,
 string action,
 object routeValues,
 string imagePath,
 string alternateText = "",
 object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        var anchorBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");

        var url = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        anchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", url.Action(action, controller, routeValues));
        var imgBuilder = new TagBuilder("img");
        imgBuilder.MergeAttribute("src", url.Content(imagePath));
        imgBuilder.MergeAttribute("alt", alternateText);
        var attributes = (IDictionary<string, object>)HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        imgBuilder.MergeAttributes(attributes);
        string imgHtml = imgBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
        anchorBuilder.InnerHtml = imgHtml;
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchorBuilder.ToString());
    }
```

and i using it in my view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   .
   .
    <div>
        Image:
        @Html.ActionImage("ControllerName", "action", 
        "routeValues", item.ImageAddress.toString())
    </div>
   .
   .
}
```

ImageAddress is string but doesn't work,there is no difference when i use a specific address like

```
@Html.ActionImage("ControllerName", "action", 
        "routeValues", "C:\1.jpg")
```

only when use this address it does work good:

```
"../../Content/Images/1.jpg"
```

what's the problem? thanks for your help, sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this problem i don't use the Extension method, i use img tag.

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/" + @item.Id + ".jpg")" />
```

i founded it in Vahid Nasiri's Ebook, learning MVC3.
http://www.dotnettips.info/

Answer (score 0):

Browsers cannot read files from the server's disk.

You can only reference images over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   .
   .
    <div>
        Image:
        @Html.ActionImage("ControllerName", "action", 
        "routeValues", @Url.Content("~/" + item.ImageAddress.toString()))
    </div>
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: What is the value of item.ImageAddress.toString()?

Comment: item.ImageAddress = "C:\\Users\\hawre\\documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\Main_Proj\\Main_Proj\\Content\\Images\\1.jpg"

Comment: as @SLaks said, your browser cannot access files from the disk, you have to add this image to your solution or access some image over http

Comment: it means there is no better solution?

Comment: I don't know any other, sorry